# Problems with svg.js, drawing centred text along an arc

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to draw a dynamic text "centred" along an arc with svg.js. Means the middle of the text is always at the topmost point of the arc.

In static html (means: without svg.js) it works fine. Something like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300">
<defs>
        <path id="myPathTop" d="M150,250 A100,100 0 1,1 151,250" />
    </defs>
    <text style="stroke: #000000;" id="idTextTop" font-family="Arial" font-size="20" text-anchor="middle">
    <textPath xlink:href="#myPathTop" startOffset="50%" id="idTextPathTop" >
            A nice, long, centred text along an arc path...
    </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Result see:
http://s28.postimg.org/wxs58d58d/svg_arctext_OK.png

The combination of 'text-anchor="middle" '  and 'startOffset="50%"' achieves the centring of the text.

In trying to do it in svg.js however I did not (yet) succeed:

```
var defs = svg.defs(); 
var path = svg.createPath(); 
//[...set some vars, then ....]
svg.path(defs, path.move(startX, startY).arc([[radius, radius, rotateX, drawLargeArc, drawClockwise, endX, endY, relativeValues]]), {id: 'myPathTop'});
var text = svg.text('', {fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: '20', textAnchor: 'middle'}); 
var texts = svg.createText(); 
svg.textpath(text, '#myPathTop', texts.string('A nice, long, centred text along an arc path...'), {id: 'MyTextPath', startoffset: 0.5} );
```

The result is:
http://s28.postimg.org/8srfqnkxp/svg_arctext_error.png

Obviously "startoffset: 0.5" is not regarded.

I checked Keith Woods svgRef.html and a couple of examples, but couldn't get it to work.

Does anybody have any idea, what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Never used this, but - isn't it case sensitive? Doesn't it need to be startOffset...? Just guessing. Changing the value doesn't do anything at all, or is it just off?

Comment: From the documentation: `text.textPath.attr('startOffset', 0.5)`

Comment: Thx a lot Jiří Eldorado Bayer and  Phrogz. I aleady tried that yesterday and it did not help. HOWEVER your feedback encouraged me to experiment more and you are perfectly right....

Finally the following fixed it
startOffset: '50%'

So... needs a capital "O" as you mentioned AND percentage instead of decimal number.

Tried it in FF, IE, Safari, Chrome, Opera => Works :-)

Thanks a lot!!